# <Anaconda3> japanize-matplotlib install error

Tags: python, matplotlib, github, conda, anaconda3

In an Anaconda3 environment, I got an error when installing japanize-matplotlib.

https://github.com/uehara1414/japanize-matplotlib
and in the Anaconda Prompt
conda install -c uehara1414 japanize-matplotlib
I got an error with a blue frame as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKvkF.png)

I would like to know the cause of the error and how to remedy it.

【Problem solved】
We found that we could not install the package because it was not Win_64 compatible. By using pip instead of conda, I was able to use japanize-matplotlib successfully. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: It's probably not part of conda. In that case it's okay to use `pip` with your conda environment. https://pypi.org/project/japanize-matplotlib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/uehara1414/japanize-matplotlib) for your specific package, you will see that it is only available for `osx-64`, not windows. As the other answer has noted, you can still install using `pip`, as there is only a source distribution on PyPi which you can probably install to windows as well

Comment: I understand very well. You couldn't use conda ~ because it was an unsupported installer. Problem solved. I will be more careful with my installer in the future.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the Anaconda Prompt, type `conda install pip`. Then use the `pip install japanize-matplotlib` command.

Comment: Thank you very much.
By the way, if anyone knows what the cause was, please let me know.

Comment: Installing with pip solved the problem. I also found out why I couldn't do it with conda~.
Thank you very much.